# Excel Macros VBA Programming - Referencing another sheet in vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a very simple piece of code giving me problems.

All I'm trying to do is a vlookup that references the previous sheet. However, I'm getting the following error: 
Compile Error: Expected: end of statement

Here is the code:

```
Range("Y2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-19],'"&ActiveSheet.Previous.Name&"'!C[-19]:C,20,0)"

Selection.Copy
Range("Y3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: So if the `ActiveCell` is on `Sheet3`, you want to reference `Sheet2` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on line to replace all 5 of yours:

```
Range("Y2:Y3").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-19],'" & Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index-1).Name & "'!C[-19]:C,20,0)"
```

Comment: love the `ActiveSheet.Index-1`

Comment: Scott - this was exactly perfect. Thank you!